# Regex string match

Tags: regex

I am attempting to create a regex that satisfies the following conditions:

Object name must:

- Be upper case
- Can contain any numbers either side of characters
- Following characters excluded anywhere '"*'&<>/

Any tips on how you achieve something like this would be appreciated.

**Valid examples**:

- SITE 10
- A23 - FLATS 12B RANGE AND ALLOWANCE PITCH.
- 2 - 9 GUARDSPACE AVENUE.

**Invalid examples**:

- site 10
- A23 / FLATS 12B RANGE AND ALLOWANCE PITCH
- 2 & 9 GUARDSPACE AVENUE

Comment: `^[A-Z\d]+$` ..... Post some valid and invalid examples.

Comment: What language? `Following characters excluded anywhere ` so every other character is allowed? Sounded like only uppercase letters and numbers were allowed. Sample input, expected output, and issues you've encountered would help this question.

Comment: Any character not listed is allowed. Can be anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved with the following regex:

```
^[^a-z'"*&<>\/]+$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zP8lT6/6)

It allows any letter that is not `'"*'&<>\/`, and requires that there is no lowercase English letter.

- `^` - Start of string
- `[^a-z'"*&<>\/]+` - 1 or more characters other than `'`, `"`, `*`, `&`, `<`, `>`, `/` or lowercase English character.
- `$` - End of string

Restricting the length can be achieved with a limiting quantifier:

```
^[^a-z'"*&<>\/]{3,60}$
```

Answer (score 1):

If you meant that the group of characters (which cannot have numbers and `"&'*<>/` ) can be preceeded and followed by numbers , You can do this:

```
^\d*[^a-z&<>"*'\/]*$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yL4xB7/3)

The above regex will allow numbers to interleave the character group i.e., it will match string like `123AB123CD123` , If you don't want to match those strings also, use following regex

```
^\d*[^a-z0-9&<>"*'\/]*\d*$
```

Also if you don't want the regex to match null string, change the `*` for character class to `+`

Comment: `[^a-z&<>"*'\/]` already allows digits, thus `\d*` is unnecessary. Capturing group is not used, I'd rather remove it for better performance. And another note is that it allows an empty string. Not sure it is expected behavior.

Comment: thanks for the update. If I was to restrict the length of the entire string, to must be between 3-60 characters, would {1,58} at the end do the trick?

Comment: @user1905307 , I updated the `DEMO` link too , you can check that it exactly matches the strings u said valid in the question and it didn't match the other invalid strings u mentioned

Comment: @user1905307: My regex allows to easily add the limiting quantifier. This one will require a look-ahead. At least in the form it is now in.

Comment: @stribizhev , I thought he never wanted the numbers to interleave in the characters in between , so I wrote my answer accordingly, Now that I see he updated question with examples and numbers can come in between and he wants to limit the length, your answer is more appropriate :)